# Dynamically generated HTML/CSS webpage, is resizing a cell in a table when hovered over it

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a table cell (X) which contains some tables/divs inside it. I am trying to add a functionality to it which adds an arrow on the side of the cell when I hover over it. The problem is that it is resizing the cell when I hover over it and then adding my required arrow. 
For the arrow I am using jQuery to create a "div" which contains a table with rows for an overlay a stroke and the arrow icon. I am appending that div to the my original cell using jQuery. 
I am setting a property with jQuery that when I hover over the original cell, that div should show. I used the jQuery method .show() to achieve that. This is adding a "display:block" in the css and causing the cell to increase in size vertically. I have tried "position:absolute" but it does not work since the original table which contains cell (X) can have many rows and each row will have a cell (X) in them and all cells will need similar arrows on the end when hovered over.

The jQuery code that I have used is:

```
    this.hover = $(document.createElement('div'));
    this.hover.prop("id", "hover");
    this.hover.addClass("person-row-hover");
    var html = '<div class="person-row-hover-stroke"></div>';
    html += '<table class="person-row-hover-table">';
    html += '<tr>';
    html += '<td class="person-row-hover-table">';
    html += '<div class="arrow-right-grey"></div>';
    html += '</td>';
    html += '</tr>';
    html += '</table>';
    this.hover.append(html);
    this.stroke = $(this.hover.children()[0]);
    this.stroke.hide();
    this.arrow = $(this.hover.children()[1].rows[0].cells[0]).children();
    var arrow = this.arrow;
    cell.append(this.hover);
    this.hover.hide();
    var hover = this;


    row.mouseover(function() {
        hover.displayArrow();
    });
            /**
   * Displays the hover arrow.
   * @param none
   */   
   this.displayArrow = function() {
       this.hover.show();
   }
```

The CSS used for this code is:

```
.person-row-hover {vertical-align:middle; text-align:center; position:relative;
   right:-300px; top:-55px; width:27px; height:20px; cursor:pointer;}
.person-row-hover-overlay {background-color:#BCBDC0;}
.person-row-hover-overlay-clicked{background-color:#CFD1D7;}
.person-row-hover-stroke {position:absolute; left:2px; width:1px; height:100%; border-  
 left:1px solid white;}
.person-row-hover-table {position:absolute; vertical-align:middle; border:0px;  
 height:100%; width:100%; z-index:5;}
```

THE HTML FOR THE CELL IS:
http://pastebin.com/VwE4x25s

THE IMAGE ON HOW IT LOOKS IS:

[image: The Cell (X)]

I have color coded it, The "div" that I append is in color black. Which has a table with arrow/stroke in it. 
The red color is the Cell (X). **AS YOU CAN SEE THAT IT BECAME BIGGER THAN THE BLACK PORTION, ORIGINALY IT WAS EQUAL IN HEIGHT TO THE BLACK DIV BUT WHEN I HOVERED OVER IT, IT GREW IN SIZE**
This webpage is run through my company's application and can only be run through IE8. So I am unable to use any Chrome stuff. If you need me to put more code out there, I will try my best as I cannot put everything due to my company's policies.
Thank You, any help will be great.

Comment: Please add a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I tried but I am unable to make it work :S, I pasted all the above code in JS Fiddle in the right sections but it does not even pull any CSS

Comment: Did you click run? And make sure it's loading jQuery?

Comment: Yes I did, and yes I did jQuery 1.8.3

Comment: Well post the link to it anyway.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zxfBj/

Comment: What is the variable 'cell'?

Comment: I was able to fix it, I kept changing the combination of absolute and relative and instead of top/right i used margin-top / margin - left and it worked. Than You screenmutt!

Answer (score -1):

I was able to fix it, I kept changing the combination of absolute and relative and instead of top/right i used margin-top / margin - left and it worked. Than You screenmutt!